# Windows Mobile - allow email entry in TextBox

Tags: windows-mobile

I have added a textbox to my WinMo app's form and I want to get an email address as the input. Right now if I type @, it just takes in the input as 'a' instead of the @ sign.

How do I allow the @ character in the textbox? I am using Windows Mobile Professional SDK and testing on the Smartphone Emulator.

Thanks

Comment: This is not programming related. The user of the phone needs to select the appropriate input method to type symbols.

Comment: This is a programming-related question. I have been developing for the iPhone and that has a keyboard specifically for entering email address. So was wondering if winmo had any such input type options for textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Smartphone's 'abc' mode interfering with your text entry. It's seeing the shift-2 as simply the '2' key, and is queuing up an a, b, or c letter (if you press it multiple times).

Since many input methods are device-dependent (some devices have a FN key you have to chord with another, others have a SYM key that pops up a symbol chooser), you are bound to whatever the device (or in this case, the emulator) uses.

To use that emulator's input method, keep pressing the 1 key - it loops through common symbols including the '@' character.